# tox/conda/travis-ci raises ImportError: _PyErr_ReplaceException

Tags: python, travis-ci, conda, tox

I want to set up Travis-CI to run the locally working test suite of a recently open-sourced Python 2.7 library. For efficiently installing dependencies like `Numpy` and `Scipy`, I found some advice to use the `Miniconda` distribution. Unfortunately, my [.travis.yml](https://github.com/pik-copan/pyunicorn/blob/ab4e537fef972dcdd686bfcf8b0232ed3abb829f/.travis.yml), which
follows the official "Using Conda with Travis CI" tutorial, after successfully installing all dependencies [produces](https://travis-ci.org/pik-copan/pyunicorn/builds/66565852) this error while initializing the `tox` environment:

```
ImportError: /home/travis/build/.../.tox/py27-nose/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyErr_ReplaceException
```

The mentioned symbol was recently added in Issue 23781 of the Python Bug Tracker. I suspect that the problem is caused by conflicting Python versions, and tried to use Python 2.7.9 as well as 2.7.10, with and without a test environment as produced by `conda create`, to no avail.

I would greatly appreciate any advice!

Comment: This is probably the underlying issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conda guys have now released a fixed virtualenv package that no longer has this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can downgrade by running `conda install python=2.7.9` and confirm it resolves your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not resolve the issue for me: [issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367#issuecomment-118861564), [travis](https://travis-ci.org/pik-copan/pyunicorn/jobs/70874595#L3624)

Comment: I got the problem in both python 2.7.13 and 2.7.10, when I use virtualenv, and it works for me using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by downgrading my Python version from 2.7.10 to 2.7.9